# split the string using "," and store in array list

Tags: c#, split

1. Here is the `string` in **C#**: `string Id = "1LE, 1GE";`
2. `Split` the `string` using *comma*.
3. Store it in `ArrayList`.

My code is *not working* on online compiler.

```
string Id = "1LE, 1GE";
ArrayList centerIds_list = new ArrayList();
centerIds_list.AddRange(centerIds);
```

I need the output as `2` elements with *spilited  string*.

Comment: `ArrayList centerIds_list = new ArrayList(); centerIds_list.AddRange(Id.Split(','));`

Comment: What is `centerIds`?

Comment: You didn't use `Split()`

Comment: And your google search for "c# split string" did not show you [`string.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)??

Comment: Are you required to use `ArrayList`? It's a really outdated class.

Comment: Why an `ArrayList` instead of a `List<string>` ?

Comment: I highly recommend that you do not use `ArrayList` it's a left over from the dark times before generics.  Either use the array that `Split` gives you or put it into a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days nobody uses `ArrayList`, instead they use a strongly typed generic. In your case that would be `List<string>`.

To get the parts as a `List<string>` you can do:

```
Id.Split(',').ToList();
```

If you want to remove any spacing around the individual parts then you can do:

```
Id.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, `string.Split` returns *array* - `string[]` so if you are not going to add / remove items, just put

```
  string[] centerIds_list = Id.Split(',');
```

If you want to add/remove items into/from the collection (and that's why *array* is out of question), try `List<string>` instead of *obsolete* `ArrayList`:

```
   List<string> centerIds_list = new List<String>(Id.Split(','));
```

Finally, if you insist on `ArrayList`:

```
   ArrayList centerIds_list = new ArrayList(Id.Split(','));
```

Few more details:

`"1LE, 1GE".Split(',')` will return `"1LE"`, `" 1GE"`, please, note *leading space*. You can get rid of it either by splitting on `", "` (not `','`):

```
   Id.Split(new string[] { ", "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Or with a help of *Linq*: `.Select(item => item.Trim())` followed by *materialization* (`.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`), e.g.

```
   string[] centerIds_list = Id
     .Split(',')
     .Select(item => item.Trim())
     .ToArray();
```

Or

```
   List<string> centerIds_list = centerIds_list = Id
     .Split(',')
     .Select(item => item.Trim())
     .ToList();
```

Or

```
   ArrayList centerIds_list = new ArrayList(Id
     .Split(',')
     .Select(item => item.Trim())
     .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing line

```
var centerIds = Id.Split(',');
```

You need to split string by `comma` and then create instance of `ArrayList`.

Try below code

```
string Id="1LE, 1GE";
var centerIds = Id.Split(','); //This was missing
ArrayList centerIds_list = new ArrayList();
centerIds_list.AddRange(centerIds);
```

As most of the comments raised this point, I want to include it as well.

Use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`.

```
List<string> centerIds_list = "1LE, 1GE".Split(',').ToList(); //One line solution
```

If you want to get rid of white spaces, then use `Trim()`

```
List<string> centerIds_list = "1LE, 1GE".Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

string Ids="1LE, 1GE";
            List centerIds_list = Ids.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
            foreach (var item in centerIds_list)
            {

```
           Console.WriteLine(item);  

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not answering the question per se, but if performance is an issue, and you are working on a large about of data to split (e.g. a large csv file), then take a look at this article as it talks about using Span as an alternative to String.split.

[https://ladeak.wordpress.com/2019/06/21/the-power-of-span/amp/?__twitter_impression=true]